# What could be causing the Segmentation Fault when attempting to print a 2D vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

This is a [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) question. I am working on my `Hash Table` assignment and I ran into some issues when trying to print the table.

Constraints:

- C++11
- No `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

class DataEntry {
public:
  std::string get_date() { return date; }
  std::string get_country() { return country; }
  int get_c_cases() { return c_cases; }
  int get_c_deaths() { return c_deaths; }
  inline void set_date(std::string set_date) { this->date = set_date;};
  inline void set_country(std::string set_country) { this->country = set_country;};
  inline void set_c_deaths(int set_c_deaths) { this->c_deaths = set_c_deaths;};
  inline void set_c_cases(int set_c_cases) { this->c_cases = set_c_cases;};

private:
  std::string date;
  std::string country;
  int c_cases;
  int c_deaths;
};

class CovidDB {
private:
  std::vector<std::vector<DataEntry*>> HashTable;
  int size = 17;

public:
  void display_table();
  bool add(DataEntry* entry);
  int hash(std::string country);
};

int CovidDB::hash(std::string country) {
  int sum = 0;
  int count = 0;
  
  for (char c : country) {
    sum = sum + ((count + 1) * c);
    count++;
  }
  return sum % size; //returns the hash
}

void CovidDB::display_table() {
  for (const auto& vec : HashTable) {
    for (const auto& entry : vec) {
      if (entry != nullptr) {
        std::cout << "[Date: " << entry->get_date() << "], "
                  << "[Country: " << entry->get_country() << "], "
                  << "[Cases: " << entry->get_c_cases() << "], "
                  << "[Deaths: " << entry->get_c_deaths() << "]" << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
}

bool CovidDB::add(DataEntry* entry) {
  time_t now = time(0);
  tm* ltm = localtime(&now);
  // DATE FORMAT: mm/dd/yy
  std::string current_date_str = std::to_string(1 + ltm->tm_mon) + "/" + std::to_string(ltm->tm_mday) + "/" + std::to_string(ltm->tm_year % 100);
  std::istringstream iss(current_date_str);
  std::tm current_date = {};
  iss >> std::get_time(&current_date, "%m/%d/%y");
  
  std::tm entry_date = {};
  std::istringstream iss2(entry -> get_date());
  iss2 >> std::get_time(&entry_date, "%m/%d/%y");
  
  if (mktime(&current_date) > mktime(&entry_date)) {
    std::cout << "[Record rejected]" << std::endl;   
    return false;
  }
  
  int index = hash(entry -> get_country());
  
  if (HashTable[index].empty()) {
    HashTable[index].push_back((entry));
  } else {
    bool added = false;
    for (DataEntry* existing_entry : HashTable[index]) {

      std::atomic<bool> valid(false);
      valid.store(hash(existing_entry->get_country()) == hash(entry->get_country()) &&
                       existing_entry->get_country() == entry->get_country());
      if (valid) {
        existing_entry->set_date(entry -> get_date());
        existing_entry->set_c_cases(existing_entry->get_c_cases() + entry->get_c_cases());
        existing_entry->set_c_deaths(existing_entry->get_c_deaths() + entry->get_c_deaths());
        added = true;
        delete entry;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!added) {
      HashTable[index].push_back(entry);
    }
  }
  return true;
  return true;
}

int main() {
  CovidDB db;

  // Create two DataEntry objects
  DataEntry* entry1 = new DataEntry();
  entry1->set_date("01/01/23");
  entry1->set_country("Slovenia");
  entry1->set_c_cases(1);
  entry1->set_c_deaths(1);

  DataEntry* entry2 = new DataEntry();
  entry2->set_date("02/02/23");
  entry2->set_country("Slovenia");
  entry2->set_c_cases(1);
  entry2->set_c_deaths(1);

  // Add the entries to the CovidDB
  db.add(entry1);
  db.add(entry2);

  // Display the table
  db.display_table();

  // Clean up memory
  delete entry1;
  delete entry2;

  return 0;
}
```

The print function seems to work fine for 80% of the time (estimate), for instance when I am pushing data from `.csv` file into the 2D vector and print it works fine, but when I try to group 2 entries of the same `hash`

eg:

```
Country: Slovenia
Date: 01/01/23
Cases: 1
Deaths: 1
```

```
Country: Slovenia
Date: 02/02/23
Cases: 1
Deaths: 1
```

It segfaults...I am aware that `SEGFAULT` means one is trying to access memory that doesn't belong to him (usually trying to deref a `nullptr`)

I tried loads of stuff before asking a question here:

**Rubber duck Debugging**

I noticed that the outer loop runs `hash-1` times by putting `std::court << "here";` in-between the loops, which means that something goes wrong when it comes to the index of the `entry`.

I also changed `auto` to `std::vecotr<DataEntry*> vec` and to `DataEntry*` since the outer vector is a vector of vectors and the inner vectors are vectors of `DataEntry` pointers.

**Debugging**

I tried debugging the executable with `gbd`, since I can't configure my Vs Code debugger, but it throws an error

```
Missing separate debuginfos, use: yum debuginfo-install glibc-2.28-211.el8.x86_64 libgcc-8.5.0-16.el8_7.x86_64 libstdc++-8.5.0-16.el8_7.x86_64
```

I googled it and the only solution I found was to root install these libraries, which I can't, since this is the school's server and running `sudo` will get me kicked off.

I tried the XCode debugger but for some reason my code there runs differently...Could it be because the `ssh` is Linux and the other one isn't?

**Guards**

I added "guards" to prevent printing an empty hash table, and a guard so that I'm not de-referencing a `nullptr`, unfortunately, had no effect.

Comment: `delete entry;` -- If `entry` was not allocated with `new`, this is wrong.

Comment: `entry` is allocated with `new`. I was made aware on SO that saying `DataEntry *entry = new DataEntry` is the Java style of C++ programing but that's the way I was taught to allocate memory in school

Comment: *but that's the way I was taught to allocate memory in school* -- `DataEntry entry;  YourHashTable.add(&entry);` --  That blows everything up.  Also, you should post a [mcve].

Comment: `delete entry;` worries me too depending on how this is called. Why don't you delete it if the entry is rejected earlier in the function? Do you have to use pointers? If not it'd be safer.

Comment: Yeah I tried doing that but the best I came up with was still at least 100 lines of code so I figured adding just the methods would be best

Comment: Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in your code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires you to show a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem. See [ask] for more information. Until you do that, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to answer your question.

Comment: Using pointers is a requirement, I asked a similar question here not long ago and I was told to make my own pointer wrapper but I failed to do that... `delete` is there because I was leaking 17million bytes of memory and that was the only quick way to fix it.

Comment: 100 lines of code is acceptable for a [mcve]. Several hundred gets a little more iffy.

Comment: @TheCompile-TimeComedian `DataEntry *entry = new DataEntry;  YourHashMap.add(entry);` -- and now you've possibly messed up `entry` by pulling the rug from under me and deleting it.  What if I want to use `entry` later on after the `add`?  Now I can see why your code is having issues.  This is why your class should *leave entry alone -- don't delete it*.  Having the class call `delete` is no fix.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so you are saying I should only delete in the destructor? Because I tried that and that still leaks memory, my professor's explanation was that because the vector is created on the stack the prog won't call the destructor until all the memory is deallocated. I tried putting "here" in my destructor and it was never printed. Please don't come at me saying I don't understand basic OOP (which is true, I'm still learning how to C++)

Comment: @TheCompile-TimeComedian The problem I mentioned should be easily understood.  Your `main` function allocated an `entry`, and your `add()` function potentially deletes that entry that `main` added.  If in your code you are not showing us (yet), you've used `entry` subsequent to `add`, and `add` deleted it, or if you stored `entry` somewhere for later use and you now attempt to use it, that is a problem.  You don't need to know OOP to understand the concept of pointer ownership.  The only thing your class should be deleting is memory allocated by your class -- nothing more than that.

Comment: I had to add a constructor to `CovidDB` to resize the `HashTable` vector, otherwise it was empty. I also had to comment out the time check because it was rejecting both entries and the delete for the entry that would be deleted in `add`. After that it seems fine to me. Still some odd choices like `std::atomic<bool>`. *shrug* https://godbolt.org/z/E4TjoWxfv

Comment: OK, the code you posted -- how do you know you can `delete` the entry's at the end of `main`?  What if your class deleted them already?  That is a double-delete error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah you're right. I commented out `delete` in add and now it works, but I am also leaking a lot of memory now... a problem for another day. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RetiredNinja can I ask why is the `mktime` part commented out? is it useless or does it not make sense? I never use `iomanip` besides `std::setw()`, but I found a question here that said that that's how date validation is performed

Comment: @TheCompile-TimeComedian The `mktime` stuff is not necessary.  All you should care about is what happens if you add, search for, and remove entries.  The answer I gave below is just one issue -- there could be others.  Also, your requirement of not using `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` -- if you did use them, how would you have written your code that is equivalent to what you're doing now?  Do you think `std::map` is going to do a `mktime` internally somewhere?  That's why in this context, `mktime` and all that date stuff is not important to the issue.

Comment: @TheCompile-TimeComedian It may work differently on godbolt due to locale differences or whatever. It was preventing the code where you had an issue from running so I just skipped it to get to the important part. If it works for you then it's probably fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the `main` program, one issue is in `add()`, at the very first line after the date code:

```
int index = hash(entry->get_country());
if (HashTable[index].empty()) {
    HashTable[index].push_back((entry));
}
```

The `HashTable` is an empty vector, yet you are accessing it at `index`, which is out-of-bounds.

If you used `at()` instead of `[]`, the error should become obvious.

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/fxsK6cc4P)

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 6) >= this->size() (which is 0)
```

---

Edit: Since you mentioned that the constructor resizes the internal vector to 17 entries, the other potential error is that the `add()` function `delete`'s the entry that was passed, but your `main` program also `delete`'s the same entry after `add()` is called.

```
bool CovidDB::add(DataEntry* entry) {
//...
if (valid) {
        existing_entry->set_date(entry -> get_date());
        existing_entry->set_c_cases(existing_entry->get_c_cases() + entry->get_c_cases());
        existing_entry->set_c_deaths(existing_entry->get_c_deaths() + entry->get_c_deaths());
        added = true;
        delete entry;  // <-- This will issue a delete call on entry
        break;
```

...

```
int main()
{
   ...
   // Clean up memory
   delete entry1;
   delete entry2;
```

The fix is to remove the `delete` in the `add()` function.

Comment: yeah, sorry that's kinda my bad. I forgot to add my constructor...`size = 17` and the constructor is just `HashTable.resize(size);` so it's not going out of bounds I belive. Appreciate the answer tho

Comment: I updated the answer.  Note that still, you should check if `index` is within bounds of the vector, regardless of the size you the vector.